# выдает ошибку: ReferenceError: number is not defined

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, типы-данных

Пробую писать код, через цикл в цикле написал функцию для вывода первого элемента из каждого массива [1, 4, 7]. Но выдает ошибку: ReferenceError: number is not defined.  Если number обернуть (зачем оборачивать в кавычки, если тип данных число, а не строка) в кавычки то ошибки нет, но и console.log(board.slice(i, 0)); тоже нет

```
let board = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
  ]
function enumeration (i, j) {
  for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      if (board.slice(i, 0) === number && board.slice(0, j) === number) {
        console.log(board.slice(i, 0));
      }
    }
  }
}
enumeration();
```

Comment: А что у вас number ? Вы нигде не определили эту переменную. И `.slice` выдаст массив, а не число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно применяете проверку на тип.

Чтобы это сделать надо использовать оператор **[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**, который, в свою очередь, будет возвращать наименование типа в строковом формате, например

```js
console.log(typeof 42);
// expected output: "number"

console.log(typeof 'blubber');
// expected output: "string"

console.log(typeof true);
// expected output: "boolean"

console.log(typeof undeclaredVariable);
// expected output: "undefined"
```

(а вот сами **[Типы данных](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)**)

> 6 типов данных являющихся примитивами:
>
> - Undefined (Неопределённый тип): typeof instance === "undefined"
> - Boolean (Булев, Логический тип): typeof instance === "boolean"
> - Number (Число): typeof instance === "number"
> - String (Строка): typeof instance === "string"
> - BigInt: typeof instance === "bigint"
> - Symbol (в ECMAScript 6): typeof instance === "symbol"

---

Как следствие, вам, чтобы проверить на то, что этот тип является численным надо писать так:

```
if (typeof  board.slice(i, 0) === 'number' && typeof board.slice(0, j) === 'number')
```

---

Ну а в текущем виде вы просто пытаетесь сравнить число с какой-то переменной по имени `number`, которой не существует в текущем коде